# Magento 2 Shipping to Multiple Addresses using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipping-address, multishipping

Has anyone tried creating order with multiple shipping addresses using REST API? I can see the option in the admin dashboard to enable such functionality, but I cannot find any documentation if it is or not possible.

To be clear, I'm talking about use cases when part of the order is shipped to address A with shipping method X and the rest of the order is shipped to address B with method Y.

Alternatively, I'd also be interested in use case where we send order to one address, but some products are sent using shipping method A, and the rest of the products are shipped using shipping method B.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?